# How to use an OR clause to filter an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, option-type

I am trying to filter an array of objects in Swift by matching username or full name.

```
   filteredRegUserArray = regUserArray.filter {
                $0.userName.lowercaseString.hasPrefix(lowercasePrefix) || 
                $0.fullName.lowercaseString.hasPrefix(lowercasePrefix)}
```

Comment: you need full match? or only prefix match?

Comment: Your code seems correct. What's the problem?

Comment: Weirdly enough, the exact same line of code seemed to work today when I tried.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out!

Comment: It turns out the error was due to that some of the values in the array were nil (you do not have to give a full name on sign up).  Set all nils to "  " on the array fill to compensate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Your scenario

So it looks like you have I struct (or class) like this

```
struct User {
    let userName: String?
    let fullName: String?
}
```

You also have an array of users

```
let users = [User]()
```

### Your problem

Now when you try to filter your array

```
let lowercasePrefix = "abc"

let filtered = users.filter {
    $0.userName.lowercaseString.hasPrefix(lowercasePrefix) == true
    || $0.fullName.lowercaseString.hasPrefix(lowercasePrefix) == true
}
```

you get an error.

### The explanation

This is happening because `userName` and `fullName` are defined as optionals. In this case you cannot simply write `$0.userName.lowercaseString` because the compiler cannot be sure there is a value inside `userName`. And it will stop you from reading the `lowercaseString` property on a `nil` value in order to prevent a crash.

### Your (wrong) solution

It seems you fixed the problem changing your struct this way

```
struct User {
    var userName: String = " "
    var fullName: String = " "

    init(userName:String, fullName:String) {
        self.userName = userName
        self.fullName = fullName
    }
}
```

Let me say this is ugly. It also is something Swift tried to fight since the very beginning. The idea is that you should **NEVER** use a value like `0` or an `empty String` (or curiously a `blank space` like in this case) to indicate the absence of value. **Absence of value must be expressed with `nil`.**
So while this solutions does compile it is very bad by a design point of view and will probably cause you some problems in the future.

### Solution 1

Never accept `nil` values for the properties of `User`

```
struct User {
    let userName: String
    let fullName: String
}

let users = [User]()

let lowercasePrefix = "abc"

let filtered = users.filter {
    $0.userName.lowercaseString.hasPrefix(lowercasePrefix) == true
    || $0.fullName.lowercaseString.hasPrefix(lowercasePrefix) == true
}
```

### Solution 2

If a user could have a `nil` value as `userName` or `fullName` (it's you app and only you can answer this question) then just manage this possibility

```
struct User {
    let userName: String?
    let fullName: String?
}

let users = [User]()

let lowercasePrefix = "abc"

let filtered = users.filter {
    $0.userName?.lowercaseString.hasPrefix(lowercasePrefix) == true
    || $0.fullName?.lowercaseString.hasPrefix(lowercasePrefix) == true
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Both solutions are far better than mine.  I had the code replacing nil values with "  " as the the data is loaded from our back end.